# Mule with Facebook connector - OAuth access token could not be extracted from

Tags: facebook, mule, mule-component

I m using below code to authorize Facebook API. but m getting error -
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OAuth access token could not be extracted from: {"access_token":"EAAJmNrYXQ4wBAFJIv69EuGaeUlh8LZCAUsZBLMlp8IDbyn9JLxtOsSVb3pVn6pdJb4mTzjVCrX14fBAoEuHBIOhYBSEyjPBr0l4ahOwef9l7o4BhLtzu0bACBqee7LY48OC51BDQhmea3ZANokY4KOj9HZCN6eAZD","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5112514}

```
<http:listener-config name="callback" host="localhost" port="3000" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<flow name="AutorizeFacebook" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/facebookauthorize" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <facebook:authorize config-ref="Facebook" doc:name="Authorize" />
    <set-session-variable doc:name="Save Access Token" value="\#[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']]" variableName="accessTokenId"/> 
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[flowVars['OAuthAccessTokenId']]!= null">
            <logger message="Authorization Successful" level="INFO"
                doc:name="Logger" />
            <set-payload value="Facebook Authorization Successful"
                doc:name="Set Payload" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Authorization Failed" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            <set-payload value="Facebook Authorization Failed"
                doc:name="Set Payload" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice
</flow>
```

Comment: Facebook has recently shut down API v2.2, and with 2.3 the format the access token is returned in was changed. Likely the component you are using isn’t able to handle that yet, and needs to be updated.

Comment: So Mule facebook connector needs to be upgraded with modified Facebook API v2.3 access token in to the current Anypoint Exchange Facebook connector?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use mule. But I know that this "recent" change caught a lot of people by surprise. And since the error message says it can't decode what is obviously JSON, and that is what the format was changed to, I am pretty sure it's the exact same reason.

Comment: Maybe there's an init/config section somewhere, where you specify the API version to use? If so, and you had that set to <= 2.2 until now, try 2.3 - maybe it has the ability to parse the access token differently already built-in, if it is not way old.

Comment: I am using facebook connector version 2.3.4 still facebook connector returns an error ----********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to fetch access token.
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /DynamicFlow-localhost:3000\/callback/processors/0/1 @ test-fb-authorization-api

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to change in Facebook API, `accessToken` is returned in a JSON string.

The Regex for the access token is `\"access_token\":\"([^&]+?)\"`

and for expiration time you have `\"expires_in\":([^&]+?),")`

Use DEVKIT to install connector to your studio by cloning facebook repo

- Clone updated facebook connector project from 
  https://github.com/mulesoft/facebook-connector
- import to studio as anypoint connector project
- install connector to your studio and use facebook connector in your flows